# Need to select data in a specific format

Tags: sql

I have a table like below:

[image]

i need data like below format:

[image]

For a particular 'Polnum' If any of the field is 'Yes' then need to show 'Yes' in that field
otherwise 'No'

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: Also please tag which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: What have you tried? `select distinct`

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELCT POLNUM, 
MAX(EFT), MAX(ONLINE_BANKING), MAX(MOBILE_BANKING), MAX(CHEQUE),MAX(CASH) 
FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY POLNUM
```

this works because "Yes">"No" when you compare strings.